# Laravel Lighthouse - Adding Types Programmatically using TypeRegistry. How exactly?

Tags: laravel, graphql, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse, graphql-php

I've been unsuccessfully trying [this part in the documentation](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/digging-deeper/adding-types-programmatically.html#using-the-typeregistry) and have not found any good reference on it on the internets. I want to dynamically add schema types and thought that adding them through the typeregistry in GraphQLServiceProvider would be it but when I try to use the type in graphql-playground, it shows a **Type can not be found on schema** error. It seems that the type I registered isn't loaded into the schema which I don't know how to do.

Things I've tried:
Added the provider to my app config.
Ran "composer dump-autoload"
Cleared cache and config.

Here's my code for GraphQLServiceProvider

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Providers;

use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ObjectType;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\TypeRegistry;

class GraphQLServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @param TypeRegistry $typeRegistry
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(TypeRegistry $typeRegistry): void
    {
        $typeRegistry->register(
             new ObjectType([
                 'name' => 'Comment',
                 'fields' => function() use ($typeRegistry): array {
                     return [
                         'id' => [
                            'type' => Type::id()
                         ],
                         'content' => [
                            'type' => Type::string()
                         ],
                         'date_created' => [
                            'type' => Type::string()
                         ],
                         'updated_at' => [
                            'type' => Type::string()
                         ]
                     ];
                 }
             ])
        );
    }
}
```

and here's my schema

```
"A datetime string with format `Y-m-d H:i:s`, e.g. `2018-01-01 13:00:00`."
scalar DateTime @scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\DateTime")

"A date string with format `Y-m-d`, e.g. `2011-05-23`."
scalar Date @scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\Date")

type Query {
    users: [User!]! @paginate(defaultCount: 10)
    user(id: ID @eq): User @find
    posts: [Post!]! @all
    comments: [Comment!]! @all
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    created_at: DateTime!
    updated_at: DateTime!
}

type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    content: String!
    created_at: DateTime!
    updated_at: DateTime!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you register **GraphQLServiceProvider**? All service providers are registered in `config/app.php`, add your provider to the array like:

```php
'providers' => [
    // Other Service Providers
    App\Providers\GraphQLServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried you peace of code in my project, and it works. So you code is actually fine.

Please check you lighthouse config, probably you have cache enabled. You can enable/disable cache with `LIGHTHOUSE_CACHE_ENABLE` environment variable (`true`/`false`).

If you use lighthouse cache (like in production), don't forget to clear lighthouse cache after changes with `php artisan lighthouse:clear-cache`

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to inject in the schema is like this:

```
use GraphQL\Language\AST\EnumTypeDefinitionNode;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Modules\AccessControl\Entities\Permission;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Events\ManipulateAST;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\AST\PartialParser;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Factories\DirectiveFactory;

class GraphQLEnumPermissionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(DirectiveFactory $directiveFactory, Dispatcher $dispatcher): void
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable(with(new Permission)->getTable())) {
        $permissions = Permission::all();
    }
    else {
        $permissions = (object) [ (object) ['id' => '0', 'ui_name' => 'bar']]; // to pass the schema validation when is empty
    }

    // we need to check if we have permissions in the system
    $dispatcher->listen(
        ManipulateAST::class,
        function (ManipulateAST $manipulateAST) use($permissions): void {
            $manipulateAST->documentAST
                ->setTypeDefinition(
                    static::createEnumType(
                        'EnumObjectName',
                        'EnumObjectName description',
                        $permissions
                    )
                );
        }
    );
}

public static function createEnumType(string $name, string $description, object $enumValues): EnumTypeDefinitionNode
    {
        $enumDefinition = "\"$description\"\n";
        $enumDefinition .= "enum $name {\n";
        foreach ($enumValues as $i => $permission) {
            if(!empty($permission->description)) {
                $enumDefinition .= "\"{$permission->description}\"\n";
            }

            $enumDefinition .= $permission->ui_name . " @enum(value: \"".$permission->id."\")\n\n";
        }
        $enumDefinition .= "}\n";

        return PartialParser::enumTypeDefinition($enumDefinition);
    }
}
```

The directive @whereConstraints is written like this